# Filtering: An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have this project, and I have api and through this api, the users in the Database are returned, but in the response, data is returned in addition to two variables, the first “isActive” and the second “isVerified”, and through these two values ​​I can control the display, which means I can control the The data values ​​that will be displayed on the interface,

If the value of the previous two variables is False, it means that the user has been rejected. Therefore, I save the rejected user in the "UsersRequests" array, and then I display the values ​​in the "UsersRequests" array on the interface called "Users Requests"

And if the value of the previous two variables is true, then this means that the user has been accepted and has become a user of the site, so I save the user in the array “Users”,
Then I display the values ​​in the "Users" array on the interface called "Users".

And based on the previous cases, I filtered the values ​​​​coming from the backend

But I got this error:

```
[Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.
```

How can I solve the problem?

```
import {
  createSlice,
  createAsyncThunk,
  createEntityAdapter,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const getUsersRequests = createAsyncThunk(
  "usersRequests/getUsersRequests",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("/users/for-admin")
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    const usersRequestsData = response.data.data;
    console.log("data inside Slice:", usersRequestsData);
    return usersRequestsData;
  }
);

// This is one of the keys 'slice name' which is 'usersRequests'
const contactsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "usersRequests",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    usersRequests: [],
    status: null,
    approve: null,
    acceptedUsers: [],
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getUsersRequests.pending]: (state) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [getUsersRequests.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.data = payload;
      console.log("inside coooontact Slice: ", state.data);
      return state.data.filter((user) => {
        if (user.isActive == false && user.isVerified == false) {
          state.usersRequests = user;
        } else {
          state.users = user;
        }
      });
    },
    [getUsersRequests.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.status = "failed";
    },
    
});

export default contactsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two trouble for me :

One in the extraReducer you need to use builder like that :

```
extraReducers:(builder) => {
    builder.addCase(-typeAction-, state => {
     //doSomething...
      // state.value = newValue;
    });
  }
```

See : https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice

Second trouble (less) :

```
 return state.data.filter((user) => {
    if (user.isActive == false && user.isVerified == false) {
      state.usersRequests = user;
    } else {
      state.users = user;
    }
  });
```

Try to change for :

```
 state.data.forEach((user) => {
    ...
```

D'après MozillaDev :
La méthode forEach() permet d'exécuter une fonction donnée sur chaque élément du tableau.
La méthode filter() crée et retourne un nouveau tableau contenant tous les éléments du tableau d'origine qui remplissent une condition déterminée par la fonction callback.

So you return a value on a Reducer with redux-toolkit, Immer don't like that.

Say me if it's good for you.

//edit

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
builder
  .addCase(getUsersRequests.pending: (state) => {
  state.status = "loading";
}),
.addCase(getUsersRequests.fulfilled: (state, { payload }) => {
  state.status = "success";
  state.data = payload;
  console.log("inside coooontact Slice: ", state.data);
  state.data.forEach((user) => {
    if (user.isActive == false && user.isVerified == false) {
      state.usersRequests = user;
    } else {
      state.users = user;
    }
  });
}),
.addCase(getUsersRequests.rejected: (state) => {
  state.status = "failed";
}),
```

Comment: can u edit my code please?

Comment: Done, say me if it's good

Comment: no, not good, can you take my code above and edit it pleeeeaaaaase

Comment: Sorry, I edit an another post with this :)

Comment: my problem was solved, but you must put ',' instead ':' in your answer

Comment: Haha, I take your code like base, I didn't be "attentif", sorry for that !

Answer (score 1):

In a reducer created with `createSlice`, the `state` parameter is an Immer draft. Your reducer function must *either* modify the draft *or* return a new object, but not *both*. As you've implemented the reducer, the assignment of the `status` and `data` properties modify the draft, but then the value produced by `state.data.filter` is returned. This causes the error message you're seeing.

Instead, iterate through `state.data` and modify the two user properties, but do not explicitly return anything from the function. It might look something like this (extracted to a named function for demonstration):

```js
function getUserRequestsFulfilled(state, { payload }) {
  state.status = "success";
  state.data = payload;
  state.data.forEach((user) => {
    if (user.isActive == false && user.isVerified == false) {
      state.usersRequests.push(user);
    } else {
      state.users.push(user);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have a function "getUsersRequests " and this function returns data from the backend, and it must be used, and for this, I used ExtraReader,
But in your answer you did not use this function, can you modify the answer to make it agree with my code?

Comment: The body of the function is the important part. Try using the body of the function I wrote as the body of your `getUsersRequests.fulfilled` function in `extraReducers`.